# How to add req.user to fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-native

I'm trying to make a post request with this code:

```
fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    // body
  }),
  user: JSON.strigify(user)
});
```

The problem is, on the backend, the server is returning undefined for req.user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure what might be wrong without seeing how you handle the request in the backend, but you most likely must put the `user` object in the `body`.

This would however end up in `req.body.user` in the backend, not `req.user`.

```
fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user
  })
});
```

Comment: Might be worth clarifying that this would result in `req.body.user` as opposed to `req.user`

Answer (score 0):

You can not send user as a top-level property in the fetch request. You can either include them in body or headers. But if you are using GET request, you might not be able to include in request body.

Here's the solution with user added in headers.

```js
fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-user-data': JSON.stringify(user) // You can send in user key as well
    }
}).then(async (result) => {
    console.log(await result.json());
}). catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
});
```